# Notational for combination of continuous and discrete density

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a continuous random variable $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ it is conventional to describe its density as a function $g$ which satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(u) du = 1$ now $\int_a^b g(u) \, du$ indicates the probability that $X \in [a,b]$. For a discrete random variable $Y$ it is conventional to describe its density as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n \delta_{a_n}$, which indicates that the probability that $Y$ equals $a_n$ is exactly $p_n$ and $\sum_n p_n =1$.

Now suppose we have a random variable which equals $a_n $with probability $p_n$ and $\sum_n p_n = p < 1$. Moreover it has a continuous part which is described by a density function $g$ satisfying $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(u)\, du = 1-p$. How do we then write down the ''density'' of this random variable? Is it simply: $g\, du + \sum_n p_n \delta_{a_n}$ where $du$ is used to denote the Lebesgue measure and $\delta_{a_n}$ the dirac delta measure on $a_n$ or are other notations more conventional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is fine. If you want to know the general form of a distribution function there is a theorem which says any distribution function $F$ is of the form $F(x)=aF_1(x)+bF_2(x)+cF_3(x)$ where $F_1$ corresponds to a discrete random variable, $F_2$ to a continuous one with density, $F_3$ is a continuous distribution which is singular in the sense $F_3'(x)=0$ almost everywhere, $a\geq 0, b\geq 0,c\geq 0,a+b+c=1$.

Comment: Can you send me a link to this theorem?

Comment: Theorem 1.3.2 of A Course in Probability Theory by K. L. Chung.